# Blazor Hybrid MAUI APP : How to Access GPS location when using WebView.?

Tags: maui-blazor

I am re-using the Blazor wasm UI & code that display the google Map and location of user.
based on user location i display/plot markers of the nearby businesses.

My google Map Project is Razor Class Library (RCL) Project with JavaScript to render the google map, display current location marker and code to display list of markers for business.

I have been able to successfully load the Google MAP RCL Project into Blazor Hybrid, but not able to get the current location of user.

I have added the following permission to android manifext.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
```

what else am i missing to obtain the current location of user ?

Answer (score 0):

As for the permission, you've got them all. You'll need to check the rest of your source code